# Utilizar dados do componente no método create no VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando passar dados de um componente para outro usando o método do $bus:

```
Vue.component('porcentagens',{
data: function(){
    return {
        porcentagemSangramentoMarginal: 0,
        porcentagemPlaca: 0,
        porcentagemOLeary: 0,

        selecionadosSangramentoMarginal: [],
        selecionadosPlaca: [],
        selecionadosPorcentagemOLeary: []
    }
},

created(){
    this.$bus.$on('faceSelecionada', function(idFaceSelecionada){

        if(idFaceSelecionada.charAt(0) == 's'){

        }

    })
},
```

Ele está escutando o evento 'faceSelecionada' normalmente e recebendo o parâmetro também, porém não consigo acessar os dados do próprio componente: ao receber o evento com parametro preciso adicionar o id recebido na lista dentro de data e mudar o valor que também está contido em data, mas ele não consegue acessar de jeito nenhum, já tentei usando o this e $.

Comment: Tente utilizar o lifecycle `mounted` no lugar de `created`

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que usar uma função "normal" (`function`) muda o contexto de execução, e o `this` dentro dessa função não é o que esperas...

Tens duas soluções:

#### Usa Arrow functions

E assim o `this` é o mesmo que era fora da função:

```
created(){
    this.$bus.$on('faceSelecionada',(idFaceSelecionada) => {
        if(idFaceSelecionada.charAt(0) == 's'){

        }
    })
},
```

#### Usa um alias para o `this`

Se fizeres `const self = this;` fora da função podes então usar o `self` em vêz do `this` dentro da função pois essa variável não é alterada.

```
created(){
    const self = this;
    this.$bus.$on('faceSelecionada', function(idFaceSelecionada){

        if(idFaceSelecionada.charAt(0) == 's'){
          // aqui podes usar self.algumaPropriedadeReactiva = idFaceSelecionada;
        }

    })
},
```